# Difference between ('#ID') and $('#ID') selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between these two selectors: `('#ID')` and `$('#ID')` in jQuery?

When I am calling my function `checkSpecialChars('#txtCreateSet')`, it does not work and shows the following error message:

```
error Object doesn't support this property
```

However, when I call my function like the following: `checkSpecialChars($('#txtCreateSet'))`, it works. Why is this the case?

Comment: No such thing as `('#ID')` that's just a string surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: Why the downvote, it is a valid question, just one with an easy answer, for someone who doesn't understand this I can see why it would not seem obvious!

Comment: on modern browsers, you could use $(ID)

Comment: Yeap, this was one of the first questions I had with jQuery. This and that `$(function () {})` thing (equivalent to `$(document).ready(function () {})`). These stuff can be really complicated to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` in jquery is a `function` that initiates an object, that object has access to all of jquery's functionality.

Without declaring the `$` you are just defining a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

`('#ID')` is just a string while `$('#ID')` is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

`$` indicates a jquery object... inside of jquery I should say, not native javascript. There are ways to change this syntax (used when you want to have more than one JS library in a web application). You can think of `$('whatever')` as the same as `thisIsAJqueryObject('whatever')`.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery `$` is a function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements:

Answer (score 0):

`$` is the same as writing `jQuery` - it's just a shortcut to accessing the wide world of jQuery functionality.